# Checking out a remote branch from github, but I don't get an exact copy of it

Tags: git, github, git-branch

When I checkout from a remote branch, I don't get the same version that is on github.

```
$git checkout merge-pos2
M       main.go
M       miner/block.go
M       miner/blockchain.go
M       miner/blockchainparam.go
M       miner/slashing.go
M       miner/state.go
M       storage/configs.go
M       storage/seed.go
M       storage/utils.go
Switched to branch 'merge-pos2'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/merge-pos'.
```

Why are these files not copied correctly? What does the capital M in front of each file stands for? How can I get the same version as on github?

Comment: What isn't copied correctly?;

Comment: All the files that are listed were different on github compared to the newly created branch.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What about it isn't copied, though?

Answer (score 1):

M means the file has been Modified compared to the last commit.

You probably had uncommited changes before doing the checkout, and these changes have been transferred to the branch on which you checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Run `$ git commit -a -m <your commit message>`, then pull all the changes down from the github to update your local repos.

When you run the checkout command, you files will be the same